# Unable to load categoryproducts on the category page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to make a side category menu bar so when a user clicks on a certain category it must show all the products of that category but its not really working. The category page does get loaded but its not loading any products that belongs to a category. I think the links is also right when I load the category page?: `Product/category/3`

This is the error that I'm getting when I load up the category.php view file:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 42

Line number 42 in category.php: <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
```

This is my full category.php view file:

```
 <?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                         <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                 <a href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
            </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats'];; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>




</div>





<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

db_helper.php file:

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

Product.php controller file:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Product extends CI_Controller { 

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  }

  var $data = array();

  public function index()
  {
  //Laad kado uploaden view
  $this->load->view('product_form', $this->data);
  }

  public function details($product_id)
  {
    //load the Product_model
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    //call function getdata in de Product_model
    $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

    //get product details
     $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

    //laad view
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('details',$data); 
  }
  //categorie product functie
  public function category($id)
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Category';
    $data['page'] = 'Product/category';
    $data['category'] = $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->findByCategory($id);
    $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
    $this->load->view('category', $data);
  }
```

Category_model file:

```
<?php
class Category_model extends CI_Model {
    public function findByCategory($id)
          {
              $this->db->select('*'); 
              $this->db->where('id', $id);
              $q = $this->db->get('categories');
              if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
                  foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
                      $data[] = $row; 
                  }
                  return $data; 
              } 
          }
}
?>
```

Product_model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
      public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('users.user_id,users.email,users.voornaam,products.product_id,products.category_id,products.product_naam');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }


    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('products')->result();
    }


    public function findByCategory($id){
              $this->db->select('*'); 
              $this->db->where('id', $id);
              $q = $this->db->get('categories');
              if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
                  foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
                      $data[] = $row; 
                  }
                  return $data; 
              } 
          }
}
?>
```

Database tables :

1.products -product_id

2.categories -id -name

When I print like this:

```
 :
```

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 75
            [product_naam] => Testcadeautje
            [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.

Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis.

Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            [user_id] => 4
            [ophaal_plaats] => Arnhem
            [product_foto] => new_fda34b15a9652cc0d51b5f5a26fd4c84.jpg
            [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_fda34b15a9652cc0d51b5f5a26fd4c84.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-10-04
            [date_updated] => 2017-10-04
            [category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 76
            [product_naam] => 100x100 foto
            [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.

Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis.

Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            [user_id] => 4
            [ophaal_plaats] => Amsterdam
            [product_foto] => new_b5fb5053c4374f35eda29cc70bc9f6a5.png
            [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_b5fb5053c4374f35eda29cc70bc9f6a5.png
            [date_created] => 2017-10-04
            [date_updated] => 2017-10-04
            [category_id] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 77
            [product_naam] => Testcadeau
            [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.
            [user_id] => 4
            [ophaal_plaats] => Testing
            [product_foto] => new_6c1bed3faeb30af3d3c0f57af902b03a.jpg
            [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_6c1bed3faeb30af3d3c0f57af902b03a.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-10-05
            [date_updated] => 2017-10-05
            [category_id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 78
            [product_naam] => Testingcadeau
            [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.
            [user_id] => 4
            [ophaal_plaats] => Teststad
            [product_foto] => new_a259245f58b92408783584ea4b7d2713.jpg
            [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_a259245f58b92408783584ea4b7d2713.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-10-05
            [date_updated] => 2017-10-05
            [category_id] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 79
            [product_naam] => Testingcadeau
            [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.
            [user_id] => 4
            [ophaal_plaats] => Rotterdam-Zuid
            [product_foto] => new_59129cf7c3647901115b37a26315cafd.jpg
            [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_59129cf7c3647901115b37a26315cafd.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-10-05
            [date_updated] => 2017-10-05
            [category_id] => 6
        )

)`

Comment: $products() ? or do you mean $products or products() which returns an array which would need to be referenced as $this->products() and be defined within the controller or parent classes or if it comes from a model... or it is a helper function in which case products() would work.

Comment: It appears you are passing in $product as an array so you will either want to change it in your controller to $data['products'] = ........

Answer (score 1):

$products is a variable and you are using it as a function. Try this code:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are passing in $product as an array 
via

```
//get product details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
```

so you will  want to change it in your controller to $data['products'] =

```
//get product details
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
```

And perform the change as **usman ikram** suggested in your view. 
That will fix that particular error.

**UPDATE**

Since the Op has provided the output of $products...

The output is an associative array - so you would reference, product_id , for instance, like...

```
$product['product_id'];
```

And likewise for all the others...

**Update 2:**
Sample Test Code for Debugging

Try something like this to help understand what is going on.

```
function test_product_array() {
    // create a test array
    $test_array = array(
        ['product_id' => 1, 'category_id' => 1],
        ['product_id' => 2, 'category_id' => 2],
        ['product_id' => 3, 'category_id' => 3]
    );

    echo ' Display the Array using print_r <br>';
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($test_array); // Prove the array format is the same
    echo "</pre>";

    echo '<br><br>';
    // Display the results
    foreach ($test_array as $product) {
        echo ' Product ID: ' . $product['product_id'];
        echo ' Category ID: ' . $product['category_id'];
        echo '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

So going by your array output, this is a simplified version of it.

Comment: Getting these errors if I try it like that: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$product_id

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 42

Comment: Than I wont be able to echo product information on the category page?

Comment: Ok but now im somehow getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 42

Comment: Just start simple to understand whats going on. Try out the test example in Update 2 ... Does that work for you?

Comment: I tried to do test example 2 and it does not work for me? I get this error sir: A PHP Error was encountered



Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: test_array


Filename: views/category.php


Line Number: 23




 
Backtrace:


 
  
 
  
 
  
   

   File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/category.php

   Line: 23

   Function: _error_handler   



  
 
  
   File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php

   Line: 42
 Function: view   
File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: can you help me

Comment: And also i made some changed in my findbycategory function and I get this error now do you know what it means: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 53

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/category.php
Line: 53
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 42
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Well hang on, now we're shooting off on all sorts of problems... But the same debugging applies - print_r or var_dump your arrays and view them to see what is happening...

Comment: Well when I print the test array its not working and I get an error. And when I print the $products array it does work, look at my question on the bottom u see the output of $products

Comment: So if you copy and paste that very same function it doesn't work? I've just tried it again and it has no problems! So what have you actually done?

Comment: What is your development system?

Comment: what do you mean? My ide?